# How to shrink the boxes when the window itself shrinks

Tags: html, css

```css
<!-- CSS --> 
<!--   Nice animation and a box which has to be resized, I know it has something to do with media thing --> 
  .profile-card {
  background: #FFB300;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid silver;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 70px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  -webkit-animation: init 0.5s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19) forwards, moveDown 1s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) forwards, moveUp 1s 1.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) forwards, materia_landscape 0.5s 2.7s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) forwards;
  animation: init 0.5s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19) forwards, moveDown 1s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) forwards, moveUp 1s 1.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) forwards, materia_landscape 0.5s 2.7s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) forwards;
}
<!-- Box --> .articles {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid silver;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 300px;
  background: #FFB300;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 82%;
  top: 90%;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 70px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  -webkit-animation: init 0.5s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19) forwards, moveDown 1s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) forwards, moveUp 1s 1.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) forwards, materia_landscape 0.5s 2.7s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) forwards;
  animation: init 0.5s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19) forwards, moveDown 1s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) forwards, moveUp 1s 1.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) forwards, materia_landscape 0.5s 2.7s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) forwards;
}
.articles h1 {
  align-content: center;
}
<!-- Box --> 
 .videos {
  height: 280px;
  width: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid silver;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #FFB300;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18%;
  top: 90%;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 70px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  -webkit-animation: init 0.5s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19) forwards, moveDown 1s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) forwards, moveUp 1s 1.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) forwards, materia_landscape 0.5s 2.7s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) forwards;
  animation: init 0.5s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19) forwards, moveDown 1s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) forwards, moveUp 1s 1.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) forwards, materia_landscape 0.5s 2.7s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) forwards;
}
.videos h1 {
  align-content: center;
}
<!-- Fancy animation -->
}
@-webkit-keyframes init {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes init {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes puff_portrait {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes puff_portrait {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes puff_landscape {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes puff_landscape {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes borderRadius {
  0% {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes borderRadius {
  0% {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    top: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 40%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    top: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 40%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    background: #FFB300;
    top: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 40%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
    background: #E0E0E0;
  }
}
@keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    background: #FFB300;
    top: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 40%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
    background: #E0E0E0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes materia_landscape {
  0% {
    background: #E0E0E0;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 440px;
    height: 280px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
@keyframes materia_landscape {
  0% {
    background: #E0E0E0;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 440px;
    height: 280px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes materia_portrait {
  0% {
    background: #E0E0E0;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 280px;
    height: 440px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
@keyframes materia_portrait {
  0% {
    background: #E0E0E0;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 280px;
    height: 440px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveIn {
  0% {
    margin-top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
}
@keyframes moveIn {
  0% {
    margin-top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scaleIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes scaleIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Thought about using Javascript for this? Or does it have to be all CSS?

Comment: Use percent instead of fixed size

Comment: Use CSS comments in CSS, rather than HTML comments.